# What is the support for Chromium Embedded Framework for Yocto?

Tags: embedded-linux, chromium-embedded

I would like to know how to add CEF to my Yocto project.  At this point, I have not made any modifications to the project.  It was supplied by our board manufacturer. The board has an ARM 9.

Answer (score 2):

There is good idea to ask this question on CEF forums directly, may be someone already do something like you want (build CEF on ARMv9). In any case good starting point is digg chromium's wiki about ARM building/issues (one of page is https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxChromiumArm ). Also may be have sense ask same in chromium-dev. You not interested in whole chromium, only in 'content' module. Some time ago ARM was be impossible due to V8 restrictions, whats now - i'm not know.

Comment: Is there any link to when this question was answered on the CEF forum?

Answer (score 1):

There does exist 2 sources in GitHub for cef3, https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-browser

And https://github.com/DynamicDevices/meta-browser

I personally chose the DynamicDevices one because it actually compiled for RPI2, but I suspect it would compile for ARM9 as well, you may need to add a few patch files from OSSystems varient of the tree first though, the warnings are treated as errors in DynamicDevices' tree and therefore GCC pragma directives need to be applied first, which are contained within the OSSystems' tree itself.